# Переход на новую строчку в файле (СИ)

Tags: c, файлы

Мне надо записывать в конец каждой строки файла символ. Так вот, как после записи переходить на следующую строчку файла?

Comment: Добавлять еще один символ к строке или заменять последний? Если заменять, то ничего делать не надо. После перезаписи строки просто читаете следующую. Если добавлять, то пишите все в новый файл, а потом переименуйте его в старый.

Comment: Нужно именно добавлять символ в конец строки. А без создания нового файла никак нельзя?

Comment: В принципе можно, но очень неудобно и нерационально.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вобщем, примерно так проще всего:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE * in  = fopen("data","r");
    FILE * out = fopen("data~","w");
    if (in == NULL || out == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error open file\n");
        return 1;
    }
    char addSym = '$';
    int c;
    while((c = fgetc(in)) != EOF)
    {
        if (c == '\n') fputc(addSym,out);
        fputc(c,out);
    }
    fclose(in);
    fclose(out);
    unlink("data");
    rename("data~","data");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если текстовый файл уже существует, то читаешь построчно делая риплейс `"\r\n"` на `"{нужный текст}\r\n"` и потом сохраняешь текст.

Все.